# Trying to write at end of each line in a File in C Language?

Tags: c, file-io

I have been trying from past 3 hours and stuck at one point.
I want to add some content after each line in a File using C.

Here's My Code

```
int main(){

FILE *fp;
char c;
int p;

fp = fopen("example1.txt","r+");

if (fp == 0) {
    perror("No File");
    exit(-1);
}

while ( (c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF) {
    if (c != '\n')
        printf("%c",c);
    else {
        //Going back two points is for '\n'
        fseek(fp,-2,SEEK_CUR);
        fprintf(fp,"=2\n");
    }
}


fclose(fp);
return 0;
}
```

The Input File:

```
1+1
1+1
1+1
```

The Desired Output:

```
1+1=2
1+1=2
1+1=2
```

The Real Output:

```
1+1=2
=2
=2
=2
=2
=2
```

The Execution gets into Infinite Loop..

Comment: Or have the program work as a filter that reads one file and writes to another. Doing this in-place is hard.

Comment: Btw, `fgetc()` returns an `int` ...

Comment: If a file consisted of `"1+1\n1+1"`, (only 1 `'\n'`) should the output be `"1+1=2\n1+1=2\n"` or `"1+1=2\n1+1"`?

Comment: You can't insert characters into a file.  Using `fseek` to back up and write something else is never going to do what you want.

Comment: The reason it's going into an infinite loop is because you're appending "=2\n" to the end of the file every time. I would suggest using fseek() to offset appending "=2\n" to the end every time.

Comment: *You have to read all the lines into memory. Append to each line. Re-write the entire file.*  Even better:  Read one line into memory, strip newline if needed, append characters desired, write new line into *new* file.  Repeat until no lines in file.  Rename *new* file to original file name.

Comment: (c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF) dont work in the way you expect. fgets() return a int, convert it to a char and compare against EOF which is a int. if your char is signed, this will also be false for byte 0xFF (if CHAR_BIT is 8), if your char is unsigned, it will never be false.

Comment: dont use fseek(fp,-2,SEEK_CUR); for jump back on newline. newline is on the most systems only 1 byte and can be anything in textmode and still be valid. better, store the position before read the newline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say you have one line of text in the file.

```
1+1
```

If you look at the contents byte wise as characters, you'll see:

```
+---+---+---+----+
| 1 | + | 1 | \n |
+---+---+---+----+
```

When you encounter the `'\n'`, you go back two characters and print `"=2\n"` to the file. After, the contents of the file will be:

```
+---+---+---+----+
| 1 | = | 2 | \n |
+---+---+---+----+
```

The call to `fprintf` does not change the position from where you read the data. Hence, the read position is at the second character, `'='`, of the file.

The entire process repeats. The contents of the file remain

```
+---+---+---+----+
| 1 | = | 2 | \n |
+---+---+---+----+
```

The output continues to be

```
=2
```

after the first line.

Reading from and writing to the same file is fraught with too many pitfalls. It will be better if you separate them.

Comment: So fprintf() doesn't change the position of the file ?? will seeking further solves the problem ?

Comment: @Ashuthosh, it changes position only for the output functions such as `fprintf`, `fwrite`, `fputc`, etc. but not for input functions  such as`fscanf`, `fread`, `fgetc`, etc.

Comment: Above you said it doesn't changes for fprintf, now you are saying it changes for fprintf?? Confused

Comment: @Ashuthosh. I said *does not change the position **from where you read the data**.*

Comment: @Ashuthosh, you can use `fseek` again, after the call to `fprintf`. `fseek(fp,3,SEEK_CUR);`

Comment: yup. Its not working. More over the data is getting Over-Written. Best option is to separate the read file and write file. Thanks for your Expertise. Solved my Question. :D

Answer (score 0):

I had faced the same problem. I got it to work partially.At the desired position, I used ftell to get the current position. I subtracted this from the initial file size and stored in remainingSize variable. Using fread I got the chars after this position into a buffer. Then I wrote the desired output at current position.Then I wrote the data from buffer back into the file. This worked for small data, but there was a bug in my code which I couldn't resolve and it led to ftell returning an out of range value.

It could be explained as

if the data is

```html
+---+---+---+----+
| 1 | + | 1 | \n |
+---+---+---+----+
+---+---+---+----+
| 3 | * | 5 | \n |
+---+---+---+----+
```

let's say size of file is 'x'
You go to the point after 1.
By ftell, u can get the current pos 'y'
You have to read 'x'-'y' chars and bring them into buffer
You can write the desired output at current position and then write the contents of buffer back to the file

```html
+---+---+---+----+
| 1 | + | 1 | = | 2
+---+---+---+----+

Buf =
+---+---+---+----+
| \n | 3 | * | 5 |\n
+---+---+---+----+
```

I think this solution is inefficient as it involves many reads and writes and may not work on big files.

Answer (score 0):

You have to rewrite the entire file, other than the first line.  Trying to do that in-place to the existing file is actually pretty difficult given arbitrarily long lines in an arbitrarily-large file.

So it's much, much easier to just write a new file.

Something like this (completely lacks any error checking):

```
// open files
FILE *in = fopen( "infile.txt", "r" );
FILE *out = fopen( "infile.txt.tmp", "w+" );
// getline() variables
char *line = NULL;
size_t len = 0UL;
ssize_t result;

// buffer for output line
// (hope it's long enough...)
char buffer[ 1024 ];
for ( ;; )
{
    // getline() makes this so much easier...
    result = getline( &line, &len, in );
    if ( result == -1 )
    {
        break;
    }
    // strip newline
    char *p = strchr( line, '\n' );
    if ( p != NULL )
    {
        *p = '\0';
    }
    // append "=2" to each line
    snprintf( buffer, sizeof( buffer), "%s%s\n", line, "=2" );
    fputs( buffer, out );
}
fclose( in );
fclose( out );
// assume POSIX rename is available
rename( "infile.txt.tmp", "infile.txt" );
```

Read the file line-by-line, append the new data to the end of each line, write the new line *to a new file*, then when done `rename()` the new file to the old file name.

Normally, I'd add whitespace between lines to aid in readability, but the extra lines cause a scrollbar to appear on the code, making it *less* readable.